# In SignalR, which onDisconnected is called when we have two hubs?

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

I'm working on a problem using two signalR Hubs, when I close the navigator window (or tab) only one OnDisconnected is called.
Example pseudo-code:

```
Hub1{ ... OnDisconnected(){print(1)} }
Hub2{ ... OnDisconnected(){print(2)} }
```

on window close the output is:

```
1
```

Can someone explain me why? 
Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean client or server-side output?

Comment: I mean which event handler is executed (server side). Is Hub1.OnDisconnected or Hub2.OnDisconnected or both?

Comment: Both always. It's standard behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any client methods attached to Hub2? If not, I think the client will just ignore it and only connect to Hub1.

Comment: Yes I have two client hubs. thank you for your answer.